# Identify circular dependency in a Json object and remove all element after 2 depth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, algorithm, circular-dependency

I have a json object something like this:

```
var temp1 = {
    name: "AMC",
    children: [
        {
            name: "cde",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "AMC",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "cde",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "AMC",
                                    children: [
                                        //.............. continues as curcular depndency
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "mnp",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "xyz",
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Due to this cicular dependency, JSON.stringify is failing. 
I have done enough google and searching to get the solution for this but could not find much help.

So here basically I want to detect a circular dependency in the json object and add a new key to the object, saying cricular: true and remove all the subsequent node.

So here is the result output what I am looking :

```
var temp1 = {
    name: "AMC",
    children: [
        {
            name: "cde",
            circular: true,
            children: [ // No children here as it is curcular dependency
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "mnp",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "xyz",
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There is a way, which I think can solve it, where I can loop through all the children unless there is no children upto maximum 2 levels, but that way I will miss valid children which are having depth more than 3.

I hope my question is clear. If not please let me know I will try to expand this further.

Comment: just in case: there are [existing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-json) libraries doing such a detection as well as actual parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function solves this:

```
function check(stack,parent, obj){
    stack = stack || []; //stack contains a list of all previously occurred names
    var found = stack.find(function(parent){
        return (parent==obj.name && obj.children.length>0); //checks to see if the current object name matches any in the stack.
    });
    if(!found && obj.children.length>0){
        stack.push(obj.name); //adds the current object name to the list.
        obj.children.forEach(function(child){
            check(stack,obj, child);//recursively checks for all children.
        })
    }
    else if(found){
        parent.children=[];
        parent.circular=true;
        stack.pop(obj.name);
        return;
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
check([],temp1, temp1)
```

This leads to alteration of the original object passed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have not verified this yet.. but the logic wise it seems perfect.. So accepting this.. I will add one more comment to confirm it. Thanks Parama

Comment: Please give me feedback after trying it out! Happy to help. :)

Comment: I get error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
@Parama

Comment: Occurrence of _Maximum call stack size exceeded_  means too many function calls are happening and it's never arriving at the exit condition. Are you sure you added the return statement? I am trying to figure out why  else it would go on.

Comment: yes.. I have used exactly same function as yours.. in my input, json has 20 childs for root node.. and one of the node is having curcular dependency and it breaks there

Comment: why are u passing temp1 2 times to this function?

Comment: let's talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169196/dicussing-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

use console.table(circularObj) to help you in debugging